# SQL Server 2014 deadlock issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, deadlock

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TraceabilityReport]
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        pro.Reference, pro.BatchNumberID,
        inm.Name as 'Product Name',
        inm.code as 'Product Code',
        st.TransactionQTY, st.TransactionWeight,
        (SELECT TOP 1 b.Name 
         FROM APGoodsReceipt a 
         INNER JOIN APGoodsReceiptDetail ap ON a.APGoodsReceiptID = ap.APGoodsReceiptID
         INNER JOIN BPMaster b ON b.BPMasterID = a.BPMasterID_Supplier 
         WHERE ap.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID 
           AND ap.Deleted IS NULL 
           AND a.Deleted IS NULL) AS 'Supplier',
        (SELECT SUM(TransactionQTY) 
         FROM StockTransaction 
         WHERE StockTransaction.MasterTableID = pro.PROrderID 
           AND deleted IS NULL 
           AND StockTransaction.IsBox IS NULL) AS 'IntoSlicing',
        (SELECT SUM(TransactionWeight) 
         FROM StockTransaction 
         WHERE StockTransaction.MasterTableID = pro.PROrderID 
           AND deleted IS NULL 
           AND StockTransaction.IsBox IS NULL) AS 'WeightIntoSlicing',
        (SELECT SUM(TransactionWeight) from StockTransaction where BatchNumberID = bn.BatchNumberID and deleted is null and StockTransaction.IsBox is null and WarehouseID = 2002) as 'WeightOut',

(SELECT SUM(TransactionQTY) from StockTransaction where  StockTransaction.MasterTableID = pro.PROrderID and deleted is null and StockTransaction.IsBox is null) + (SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionQTY)),0)     
       FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID     
   WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.Name = 'Joints')) as 'TotalJointsandIntoSlicing',


(SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionWeight)),0)    
        FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID     
   WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.Name = 'Joints')) as 'Joints Dispatch Weight',

   (SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionWeight)) ,0)            

    FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID         
     WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.Name = 'Slicing')) as 'Slicing Dispatched Weight',

         (SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionQTY)) ,0)             

       FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID         
     WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.name = 'Joints')) as 'Total Joints Out', 

     (SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionQTY)) ,0)             

    FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID

     WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL 
     AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 
     AND (rm.Name = 'Slicing' or rm.name = 'Joints')) as 'Total Out',


    ((SELECT SUM(WeightReceived) from apGoodsReceiptdetail apg where apg.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID) /

    ((SELECT ISNULL((SUM(s.TransactionWeight)),0)   
        FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID     
   WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL 
   AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.Name = 'Joints')) 
   +
   (SELECT SUM(TransactionWeight) from StockTransaction 
   where  StockTransaction.MasterTableID = pro.PROrderID and deleted is null 
   and StockTransaction.IsBox is null))) as 'MC',

    ((SELECT ISNULL((count(s.TransactionQTY)),0)    
        FROM ARDispatch d
       INNER JOIN ARDispatchDetail dd
          ON d.ARDispatchID = dd.ARDispatchID
      INNER JOIN StockTransaction s
         ON s.MasterTableID = dd.ARDispatchDetailID
      INNER JOIN BatchNumber bn
         ON bn.BatchNumberID = s.BatchNumberID
        inner join RouteMaster rm
        on d.RouteID = rm.RouteID   
    inner join INMaster inm on 
         inm.INMasterID = s.INMasterID
    inner join INGroup ing on ing.INGroupID = inm.INGroupID    
   WHERE bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID AND dd.Deleted IS NULL 
   AND s.Deleted IS NULL AND S.ISBOX IS NULL AND s.NouTransactionTypeID = 7 AND (rm.Name = 'Joints') AND ing.Name like 'Honey Glazed%'))
   as 'Honey Glazed'



 from BatchNumber bn inner join PROrder pro on bn.BatchNumberID = pro.BatchNumberID
 inner join StockTransaction st on st.BatchNumberID = bn.BatchNumberID
 inner join INMaster inm on inm.INMasterID = st.INMasterID 




 where   st.NouTransactionTypeID = 2 and  pro.NouDocStatusID = 1 and 
 bn.Deleted is null and st.Deleted is null 
 and st.TransactionDate between @StartDate and @enddate
 order by st.TransactionDate
END
```

I've a script that I'm using for an ssrs report. The main query is bringing back a table of batches. For each batch, I need to break down and show the sum of stock weights dispatched. (Each stock item is associated with a batch, and there are multiple stock items associated).

In order to do so, I'm using a number of sub queries. As it's for a report run only a couple of times a day, the query efficiency isn't a major concern.

However, I'm getting a SQL error 'most' times I run the query -

> Transaction (Process ID 60) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what's causing this, and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Just as a quick-n-dirty approach: did you try to add "WITH (NOLOCK)" to your query (after each from / join)? Might already solve the problem...

Comment: Are you running Isolation level REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: If possible, I would suggest using TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT for reporting.

Comment: Tyron78, That did the trick. Thanks very much.